# Hichcharts- hidden series does not show again after updating plots twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have done something like:

1. Have a check box to change the plot's data
2. when the check box is checked/unchecked, update the series data array by calling `series[i].update()` accordingly.

But I have a problem that when a series is hidden by the user and try to check the checkbox and then uncheck, followed by reshow the series, the series does not show again.

Please note that If I only check the box once, no problem occurs, there will be problem only when we check the box more than once after we hide the series.

I have reproduce the problem [HERE (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/pGuEv/35/)

The code to update the plot is :

```
if (chart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        //chart.series[i].setVisible(true, true); // Note that if I add this code, then no problem 
        chart.series[i].update({
            data: dataArray[i]
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you base on Highcharts generated points. When series is hidden, then points don't exist and you set empty data for a series. In other words it looks like this: `chart.series[i].setData( [] );`.

I suggest to use separate arrays for data and use those for your calculations. General idea: http://jsfiddle.net/pGuEv/37/ (I know, it works a bit different, but shows how should be written)

```
var origData = [
    [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88],
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
];
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: origData[0].slice()
    }, {
        data: origData[1].slice()
    }]
});
```

And later:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < origData.length; i++) {        // original data
            var onePlotData = [];
            var sum = 0; //前面点的合计值s
            for (var j = 0; j < origData[i].length; j++) { // original data
                var value = origData[i][j];                // original data
                var point = {
                    //x: value.x,
                    y: state ? value + sum : value - sum,
                    //total: value.total
                }
                sum = point.y;
                onePlotData.push(point);
            }
            dataArray.push(onePlotData);
        }
```

Comment: Why only the second time, the series data becomes empty? I can't have the original data in that function scope in my real function, do i have a way to get all data including hidden data?

Comment: Why you can have original data? Just store that data in the local (scope) variable. Hard to say why you need to click twice on that checkbox. And yes, I suggest to store all data, including hidden one.

Comment: 1.I mean, I can't have the original data in the local function, the data is fetched somewhere else as well as charts rendering. So if possible i hope to have the data based on the highcharts object. 2. The user may check the box to see the result and change back(uncheck).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm missing something, very important probably. When creating chart, you have an access to the original data, right? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to create chart.. Now just store that data somewhere. For example, using chart: http://jsfiddle.net/pGuEv/39/ lines: `#17` and `#33`